# Tezos directory contains the lmdb database witch cannot

Tags: storage

[image]

Tezos directory contains the LMDB database which cannot be handled with this version of the node.

Comment: Hi Nathan, it is unclear what your question is?

Answer (score 3):

A guide to upgrade toward the new storage can be found [here.](https://tezos.gitlab.io/releases/october-2019.html)